# Formatting a table of values

Tags: list-manipulation

How do I display a list of values $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ in a two column format?

> `---------
>   1 | a_1 
>   2 | a_2 
>   3 | a_3 
>   ...... 
>   n | a_n`

I tried using TableFormat but this doesn't display the row number.

Comment: `TableForm[list, TableHeadings -> Automatic]`

Comment: @ciao. This makes more sense than mine.

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, please accept one of the answers below so that we can remove this question from the unanswered list. If not, please tell us how we can improve our answers!

Comment: @pre-kidney. Well, agreed, but ciao doesn't seem to like getting rep (I think when he does answer he posts as CW, which means he doesn't get any even if he gets upvoted): go read the blurb on his user page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

`ciao`'s answer makes the most sense.

```
TableForm[a /@ Range[5], TableHeadings -> Automatic]
```

**Original Post**

Try this. If your list of values is

```
a /@ Range[5]
(* {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]} *)
```

then you can do something like

```
TableForm@Transpose[{Range[5], a /@ Range[5]}]
```

or

```
TableForm@MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, a /@ Range[5]]
```

(`MapIndexed` is major overkill. I just like using it recently.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Table[{n, Subscript[a, n]}, {n, 1, 5}] // TableForm
```